# MySQL UPDATE with a list of random names

Tags: mysql, database

I need to update a column in my db with a list of random names. For example, updating 3000 rows with random names selected from a list of 10 or less.

I have searched through but I can't seem to find a solution that solves the problem when its a string, for integer this works fine:

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET columnName = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *10 );

+--------+-------------+--------------+
| number | customer_id | product_name |
+--------+-------------+-------
```

the table contains more than 10,000 values.

I need to update the table product_name column with random values from a list of about 10 names.

Comment: You need to write a bit long query - use `case statement` and then update the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ELT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) with [RAND()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) to get the random string

```
with cte as (
     select *, FLOOR(RAND()*(10-1+1))+1  as n
     from mytable)
update mytable m join cte c on c.id=m.id 
set m.mycolumn = ELT(c.n, 'Roger','Steve','Hulk','Jill','Thor','John','Arun','Mike','Bella','Mark') -- keep your 10names here
```

[***Check Demo Here***](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a55eb11378d8688edb39f19fe0844ca6)

Comment: Works with mysql `>=` 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName =LEFT(UUID(),8);
```

LEFT(UUID(),8) will result into something like 1a4328bb , always a random word